# Spring Boot and Spring Security integration in embedded Jetty environment

Tags: java, spring-security, embedded-jetty, spring-boot

I'm trying to initialize Spring Security from a `main()` method in a "fat" executable JAR with Spring Boot and embedded Jetty.
I use Spring Security with Java config (no web.xml). The problem is that embedded Jetty fails to register the  `springSecurityFilterChain` filter.

When I run the same JAR as a WAR in Jetty (`mvn jetty:run`) it works normally and I see this:

```
Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

But when running in embedded Jetty I see no `WebApplicationContext` getting initialized.

I have this `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory`:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
    JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    factory.setPort(8080);
    factory.addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {
        public void customize(Server server) {    
        // TODO: INITIALIZE SPRING SECURITY SOMEHOW...
        }
    });
    return factory;
}
```

I've tried creating a subclass of `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` but it is in conflict with my `SpringBootServletInitializer`. In my `pom.xml` I have these dependencies:

- `spring-boot-starter-jetty`
- `spring-boot-starter-logging`
- `spring-boot-starter`

When I add `spring-boot-web` it throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
```

Also I tried to register the `DelegatingFilterProxy` with Jetty but then it throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
```

I'm guessing I need to tell Jetty to use `WebApplicationContext`, but how?

Comment: Why aren't you just creating a class with a main method to run your application? Spring boot will do the setup for you. See http://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ and next to convert jar to war http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

Comment: I'm doing exactly that - just as the Spring Boot docs suggest. I just need to initialize Spring Security from `main()`.

Comment: SPring boot will do that as well as bootstrapping the Jetty container. I don't see why you are creating a container yourself as spring boot does all that for you...

Comment: I use the `ServletContainer` to boot a Jersey `ResourceConfig` class.

Comment: Still don't see why you would need to do that yourself, create a `JettyServerCustomizer` register it as a bean in your context and spring boot will apply it for you. The port etc. will all be set by Spring Boot. You could also register the config as a `ServletBean` so that it would be registered by Spring Boot.

Comment: I don't see how that would change anything in relation to the Spring Security filter chain. I've updated the code above.

Comment: What you are doing with your own custom stuff is destroying the Spring Boot ability to auto configure stuff. And hence it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I see now - removing the `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean fixed it. Thank you, sir! Please add an answer below so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setup disables Spring Boot to do its magic. Instead of setting up the container yourself let Spring Boot handle it. You can simply add your `JettyServerCustomizer` to the configuration as a `@Bean`. This will execute it and you can do your registration of whatever you need.

This still allows Spring Boot to do its magic and you have registered the additional endpoint y ou need.

Another solution could be to add the servlet as a `ServletRegistrationBean` to your configuration it will then automatically be added by Spring Boot.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something simple like that.