# Spring Boot JettyServerCustomizer | HTTPS port not opened | A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling

Tags: https, embedded-jetty, spring-boot

I am trying to use Spring Boot with embedded. I want the embedded Jetty to open a HTTPS port at 443.

After referring the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828229/spring-boot-and-spring-security-integration-in-embedded-jetty-environment#answer-23831273), I came up with this configuration:-

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyServerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;

import com.samsoft.expunto.service.UserService;

/**
 * @author Kumar Sambhav Jain
 * 
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/resources/**")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/").defaultSuccessUrl("/home", false).and()
                .requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure().and().logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
    }

    @Bean
    public JettyServerCustomizer jettyCutomizer() {
        return new JettyServerCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Server server) {
                SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
                sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("jetty6");
                try {
                    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(ResourceUtils.getFile(
                            "classpath:jetty-ssl.keystore").getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not load keystore",
                            ex);
                }
                SslSocketConnector sslConnector = new SslSocketConnector(
                        sslContextFactory);
                sslConnector.setPort(443);
                sslConnector.setMaxIdleTime(60000);
                server.addConnector(sslConnector);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Trying to run the application using spring-boot:run, I can see in logs that port 80 is opened but no HTTPS port:-

> 2014-06-10 23:41:56.932  INFO 196 --- [lication.main()] /
>   : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet' 2014-06-10
>   23:41:56.932  INFO 196 --- [lication.main()]
>   o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet
>   'dispatcherServlet': initialization started 2014-06-10 23:41:56.960 
>   INFO 196 --- [lication.main()] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>   : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 26
>   ms 2014-06-10 23:41:57.037  INFO 196 --- [lication.main()]
>   o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector       : Started
>   SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:80 2014-06-10 23:41:57.043  INFO 196
>   --- [lication.main()] .s.b.c.e.j.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer : Jetty started on port: 80 2014-06-10 23:41:57.045  INFO 196 ---
>   [lication.main()] c.s.expunto.web.config.Application       : Started
>   Application in 7.628 seconds (JVM running for 16.509)

UPDATE

---

Using this configuration:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
        implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/resources/**")
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/").defaultSuccessUrl("/home", false).and()
                .requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure().and().logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().userDetailsService(userService);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
    }

    public JettyServerCustomizer jettyServerCustomizer() {
        return new JettyServerCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Server server) {
                SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
                sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("jetty6");
                try {
                    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(ResourceUtils.getFile(
                            "classpath:jetty-ssl.keystore").getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not load keystore",
                            ex);
                }
                SslSocketConnector sslConnector = new SslSocketConnector(
                        sslContextFactory);
                sslConnector.setPort(443);
                sslConnector.setMaxIdleTime(60000);
                server.addConnector(sslConnector);
            }
        };
    }

    public void customizeJetty(
            JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory) {
        containerFactory.addServerCustomizers(jettyServerCustomizer());
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        if (container instanceof JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            customizeJetty((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container);
        }
        container.setContextPath("");
    }
}
```

I get this error:-

```
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:54)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7014349.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$24(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7014349$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ec8be680.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d7014349.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
```

Comment: There should nothing be preventing you from making it work with a simple `@Bean` annotated method. Try putting that method with inner class in the @Configuration class that is configured with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.

Comment: Moving it to class annotated with @EnableAutoConfiguration fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

As per M. Deinum advice, moving the customizers to class annotated with @EnableAutoConfiguration did the trick.

This is what worked for me:-

```
@Configuration

@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public JettyServerCustomizer jettyServerCustomizer() {
        return new JettyServerCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Server server) {
                SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
                sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("jetty6");
                try {
                    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(ResourceUtils.getFile(
                            "classpath:jetty-ssl.keystore").getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not load keystore",
                            ex);
                }
                SslSocketConnector sslConnector = new SslSocketConnector(
                        sslContextFactory);
                sslConnector.setPort(443);
                sslConnector.setMaxIdleTime(60000);
                server.addConnector(sslConnector);
            }
        };
    }

    public void customizeJetty(
            JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory) {
        containerFactory.addServerCustomizers(jettyServerCustomizer());
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        if (container instanceof JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            customizeJetty((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great. Small clarification: it's not working because your servlet container is customized in an `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, it's working because the customization is done *not* in a security configurer (Spring Security is a `Filter` so it has to be set up in a special place in the container lifecycle).